# How to change font size on small resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have caption on image carousel, when  I resize windows to smaller my caption doesn't change font size. I tried with @media query, but not working.

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3> Pont Neuf Bridge in Paris</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this, is there a way to set heading `<h5>` in CSS in this case?
CSS

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.carousel-caption{
font-size:10px;
}
}
```

Comment: Inside your media query in CSS you could be more specific: `.carousel-caption h5 { //rules }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Viewport Width](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)? It makes the font scale with the width of the browser window so no media queries are necessary.

[More Info](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Example:

```
.carousel-caption h5 {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

Comment: I thought common conception was to avoid this as it's not correctly supported on certain browsers, media queries are still the best way to go I'm afraid.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I'm assuming you didn't click the first link in my answer then? I have this working fine in my website in all major browsers

Comment: I've been to that site before, notice how the support is only partial for IE across the board, and by partial it means partial (test it) and see how responsive it is. IE makes up 10% of browser usage globally so it's important to account for it, even if that seems like a low figure.

Comment: Thank you but now to how position my caption, i wrote padding-bottom:5px;, but without success.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle If it didn't work in IE, I wouldn't have placed it on my website. See this [Animated GIF](http://i.imgur.com/FGbK3vq.gif) of it working in IE (the VW is set on the article heading).

Answer (score 3):

This will change the `font-size` of the `h5` tag for small screens:

```
@media screen and(max-width:480px){
   h5{ font-size:1.1em; } /* or whatever value */
}
```

---

*In your example code you are using an `h3` tag and not `h5`...so it's kinda weird*

Comment: Not working, i tried with h3.
I solved with viewport, thanks in any case

Comment: It's impossible it didn't work. you are mistaken my friend. I gave you what you've asked. if it's not working it must have been something wrong you did. please show us the code, or create a test page. the accepted answer's solution might very much create havoc in your design for small screens such as mobile.

Comment: I posted here my full code http://jsfiddle.net/8r7Lbbsr/ , but it's not a same look, because picture not imported and no bootstrap classes on jsfiddle i think.

Comment: @IgorSimic -  ok, I added bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/8r7Lbbsr/1/ - now what? what do you want to change? there is no `h5` on this page. also, I see you wrote what I told you there, but it won't work because it's set for an `h3` tag, which you don't have on the page. Set it to anything which **DOES** exists. Also, you need to check it in **full screen** mode, which you can see from top menu "share" dropdown.

Comment: h3 tag is in HTML box on  52. ... line.

Comment: well obviously I can't see it since it's in some sort of carousel component of bootstrap. maybe you could change the markup to something we could see so it would be easier to help in your specific situation.